# How to seperate a last listbox item from others in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, datatemplate, xaml-designer

I have a requirement to separate the last item from this listbox, How to handle it easily? I do not want to add a new button and remove that item from list box.

List box must be shown like below[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My list box code is as below ,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTO45.png

```
<ListBox x:Name="toolsNavigation"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Navigation}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTool}"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListBoxItem}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     SelectionChanged="toolsNavigation_SelectionChanged"
                     Cursor="Hand"
                     KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Thin"
                                   FontSize="17"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Padding="10,5"
                                   Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: TextBlock margin, bound to a converter that looks for IsLastProperty? or even simpler just use a trigger that looks for IsLastProperty true, and sets the margin diffrently

Comment: ListBox doesn't have IsLastProperty. Do I need to write a custom property?

Comment: Yes, and it will need to know if its the last item in the list for this to work... Note, there are other ways you could do this with a behavior and other magic, but i think this would be fairly straight forward.